# Replacing div (swapping divs)

Tags: jquery, html

I have some inputs in divs. It seems like below:

```
<div name="emailInput">
      <input type="text" name="email_1" /></div>
<div name="phoneInput">
      <input type="text" name="phone_number_1"   /></div>

<div name="emailInput">
      <input type="text" name="email_2"   /></div>
<div name="phoneInput">
      <input type="text" name="phone_number_2" /></div>

<div name="emailInput">
      <input type="text" name="email_3"  /></div>
<div name="phoneInput">
      <input type="text" name="phone_number_3" /></div>
```

But in some cases, I need to change the order of inputs. Specifically, I want to swap emails and phones locations. Result must be:

```
<div name="emailInput">
      <input type="text" name="phone_number_1" /></div>
<div name="phoneInput">
      <input type="text" name="email_1"   /></div>

<div name="emailInput">
      <input type="text" name="phone_number_2"   /></div>
<div name="phoneInput">
      <input type="text" name="email_2" /></div>

<div name="emailInput">
      <input type="text" name="phone_number_3"  /></div>
<div name="phoneInput">
      <input type="text" name="email_3" /></div>
```

To achieve my goal I write jquery code:

```
$('div[name^= emailInput]').insertBefore('div[name^= phoneInput]');
```

This code swapped whole phoneInputs divs before each emailInputs divs. How can I swap divs one by one? (The count of the inputs is unkown)

Also,

```
  $('input[name^= email]').insertBefore('input[name^= phone_number]');
```

doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('input[name^="phone_number"]').each(function(){
   var $this = $(this);
   var $prev = $this.parent().prev()
   $prev.find('input').insertAfter($this);
   $this.appendTo($prev)    
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PnT4Q/1/

You can also change the position of the div tags.

```
$('div[name="phoneInput"]').each(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.insertBefore($this.prev())   
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this.. but I think it should be something like this :

```
$('div[name=^ emailInput]').each(obj, function(i, val) {
      obj.insertBefore('div[name^= phoneInput]');

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to operate on them individually, rather than the whole selector group.

```
 $('div[name^="emailInput"]').each(function(){
      var previousPhoneInput = $(this).prev("div[name^='phoneInput']");
      $(this).remove().insertBefore(previousPhoneInput);
    });
```